# Custom drawable on mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

**rectangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" android:layout_weight="100"> 
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>

<padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"/> 

<corners android:radius="30dp"/> 
</shape>
```

**my map activity**

```
//Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chart); <-- this will get drawn on my map

Drawable rect = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle); // <-- this wont

OverlayItems itemizedoverlay = new OverlayItems(rect, this);
```

Could anyone please explain why i cant add custom shapes on my mapview? A normal png file works well, but if i try to make a custom shape and add it, it wont appear. Makes no sense to me since theyre both drawables?

Did i miss something obvious? Thanks

Comment: does your rectangle.xml exist inside drawable folder? and not drawable-hdpi or others

Comment: @HeshamSaeed `res/drawable/rectangle.xml`. Should it be in `bin/res` och just the `res` folder? I have both in my root

Comment: folder called drawable inside res folder